# Create a relationship saving the related ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have following code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :campaigns
  ...
end

class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  ...
end

class CampaignsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @campaign = Campaign.new(campaign_params)
    @campaign.user_id = @current_user.id
    ...
  end
end
```

The question is, is there a method provided by rails to do this: `@campaign.user_id=@current_user.id`?

Comment: Yes, you just did it. Is this not working?

Comment: It works, but it doesn't seem to be the right rails way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, I would use

```
@campaign = current_user.campaigns.build campaign_params
```

This will associate the campaign with the current user.